# Why doesn't my wait method wait until 30 seconds?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Why doesn't my wait method wait until 30 seconds?

My method should timeout after 30seconds if the method cannot find the element, currently return true or false without any timeout, any ideas?

```
    public boolean WaitUntilWebElementIsVisiblePredicate(WebElement element) {
FluentWait<WebElement> wait = new FluentWait<WebElement>(element)
        .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .pollingEvery(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .ignoring(NoSuchFieldException.class);

Function<WebElement, Boolean> f = new Function<WebElement, Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean apply(WebElement element) {
        if (!element.isDisplayed()) {
            System.out.println("Method failed: WaitUntilWebElementIsVisiblepPredicate, using locator: " + element.toString());
            return false;
        }
        System.out.println("Element visible, using method: WaitUntilWebElementIsVisiblepPredicate, Locator: " + element.toString());
        return true;                
    }
};
return wait.until(f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the condition in `apply(WebElement element)` returned false, the code wait for the time defined in `pollingEvery`. Then, the actual start time (which is captured at the start by FluentWait) is compared with the current time. If the difference of the `wait` start time and the current time is less than the time set in `withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` the function `f` is executed again until either the `timeout expires` or the `condition becomes true`.

So IMO, if it has returned earlier than the timeout period, the `apply(WebElement element)` seems to have returned `true`.

Look at the method signature [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html).

Comment: thanks for the comment, i even when the method returns false, it dosnt keep polling and in turning wait for a max time of 30 seconds timeout expires

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in this code except you are returing `return wait.until(f);` to a boolean fuction but I guess `until` method return type is WebElement.

Comment: the only problem i have is that i need to pass a WebElement (id locator) as a parameter